# A point from the ISO C++ draft (n3290): 3.4.3.2/2 Namespace members

Tags: c++, namespaces, c++11

A point from the ISO C++ draft (n3290): 3.4.3.2/1 Namespace members

> For a namespace `X` and name `m`, the namespace-qualified lookup set
>   *S(X, m)* is defined as follows: Let *S`(X, m)* be the set of all
>   declarations of `m` in `X` and the inline namespace set of `X` (7.3.1). If
>   *S`(X, m)* is not empty, *S(X, m)* is *S`(X, m)*; otherwise, *S(X, m)*
>   is the union of *S(N_i, m)* for all namespaces *N_i*  nominated by
>   *using-directives* in `X` and its inline namespace set.

Can somebody please explain to me this clause in plain English, translating it from this mathematical speak?

Edit:PLEASE ..........can any one provide me an example ..explaining the above point ..PLEASE .............

Comment: possible duplicate of [A point from the ISO C++ draft (n3290): 3.4.3.2/1 Namespace members](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7006938/a-point-from-the-iso-c-draft-n3290-3-4-3-2-1-namespace-members)

Comment: @user751747: I hope you're not going to ask us to translate the FDIS for you one paragraph at a time...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If in the namespace `X`, there exists at least one declaration of the name `m`, then those declarations are used for the lookup set.

Otherwise, all namespaces from `using` directives in the namespace `X` are checked for declarations of the name `m` in the same way as described above.

Or in other words : you check the namespace `X` and its `using` directives recursively for the name `m`, and stop the recursion at the level where declarations for the name `m` are found.